# Implements select statement in update clause in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to write an update SQL statement, which implements a select statement with join and group by another table.

Something like:

```
UPDATE coaches *******
```

here I would like to implement SELECT statement below:

```
SET coach_level = coach_level +1
```

This statement works correctly, but I really don't know how to use it in update statement:

```
SELECT c.first_name,c.coach_level,COUNT(pc.coach_id)
FROM coaches AS c
JOIN players_coaches AS pc
ON c.id = pc.coach_id
GROUP BY pc.coach_id
HAVING COUNT(pc.coach_id) >= 1 AND c.first_name LIKE 'A%';
```

I want to return the increased value of coach_level by one, which is a column from table coaches.

Like this:

```
SET coach_level= coach_level +1
```

Does anybody know how should I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate in the table `players_coaches` and join to `coaches`:

```
UPDATE coaches AS c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT coach_id
  FROM players_coaches
  GROUP BY coach_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
) AS pc ON pc.coach_id = c.id
SET c.coach_level = coach_level + 1
WHERE c.first_name LIKE 'A%'
```

This is MySql syntax. It can be modified if you use another rdbms.

Answer (score 0):

Use `where` clause:

```
update coaches
    set coach_level = coach_level + 1
    where id in (select pc.coach_id
                 from player_coaches pc
                 group by pc.coach_id 
                 having count(*) >= 1 
                ) and
          first_name like 'A%';
```

That said, your subquery is just checking if any row exists for the `coach`in `player_coaches`.  This can be simplified to:

```
update coaches
    set coach_level = coach_level + 1
    where exists (select pc.coach_id
                  from player_coaches pc
                  where pc.coach_id = coaches.id
                 ) and
          c.first_name like 'A%';
```